# What's the reason of error C2274: 'function-style cast' when using auto for boost::posix_time::time_duration?

Tags: c++, auto

The following piece of code:

```
auto td = boost::posix_time::seconds(1);

auto seconds = td.seconds(); // (*)

std::cout << seconds << std::endl;
```

gives the following error on CL 16:

> error C2274: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator

on the line marked with `// (*)`.

When I change the first line to:

```
boost::posix_time::time_duration td = boost::posix_time::seconds(1);
```

it compiles fine.

If I understand correctly, `boost::posix_time::seconds(1)` returns an instance of this class:

```
class seconds : public time_duration
{
public:
  explicit seconds(long s) :
    time_duration(0,0,s)
  {}
};
```

(from *boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_duration.hpp*)

and `time_duration` class exposes the public method `seconds`:

```
sec_type seconds() const
```

(from *boost/date_time/time_duration.hpp*).

So what's the problem with `auto` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first use of `auto` deduces the type as `boost::posix_time::seconds`, not as `boost::posix_time::time_duration`. In the type `seconds`, `seconds` refers to the type / constructor, and the compiler is no longer able to find the inherited, now hidden, function you intended to call.

I'd go with what you already figured out: you can declare `td` as `boost::posix_time::time_duration`.

(I'm not entirely sure what the standard says here -- it may or may not allow it. I'm focusing only on what your compiler allows.)